# Services in Bluetooth low Energy are not found everytime

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Good Morning all together,
i am developing on a BLE App, and i wrote an Activity for the GATT Connection. Now i got a Problem because sometimes the System recognize the Services and Characteristics and other times it doesn't.

Here is some of my Code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gatt);

    peripheralTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PeripheralTextView);
    peripheralTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    scanServiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_service);
    scanServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
        }
    });

    //get the Bluetooth device which comes from mainActivity
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("selectedDevice");
    String test = bluetoothDevice.getAddress();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Verbunden mit " + test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

    Log.d("GattActivity", "connectGatt()");
    mBluetoothGatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
}
```

And this is my onServiceDiscovered where sometimes i get the Services with all values but many times it does not get any:

```
       @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        //new Services discovered
        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            displayGattServices(mBluetoothGatt.getServices());
        }else{
            Log.d("GattActivity", "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }
```

I googled a lot and i think it's very similar to the sample of Google but i don't know why it sometimes Shows and sometimes it does not.

Maybe someone can help me

Comment: Maybe it is important to know which devices i tested. I used a Samsung s5 mini and a Google Nexus 5, my Advertisement is send by an OnePlus 3t via the Advtertisement Sample from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I got a Solution now hope it is the right.

First thing i did was to make sure we have access coarse location enabled.

```
    if(this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){...}
```

And second I forgot to use discoverServices() in onConnectionStateChange()

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {.... mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices()...;}
```

After i did These two things it works everytime (tested about 50 times hope it will work now)
But if u know a better solution be free to answer me